# Table contains the column but i still get 'Invalid Object Name' Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have a table called tbl_images in my database

`Name       |Owner |Type        |Created_datetime
TBL_Images  |dbo   |user table |2013-06-18 04:24:01.847`

this table contains the column - `SalesOrganization`

I still get the Error as below:
`Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'SalesOrganization'.`

QUERY
`Select count(*) tbl_images WHERE SalesOrganization = '5000'`

TABLE DESIGN SCREENSHOT:

[image]

Comment: Show your query which caused the issue. BTW the column `SalesOrganization` is missing in your table design?

Comment: @AishvaryaKarthik - Added the query simple select count statement. column is present

Comment: Where is the column `SalesOrganization` in your table design?

Comment: Attached table design screenshot!

Comment: It is not there in the table's design?

Comment: are you querying different db?

Comment: It is there, When i Alt +F1 on table name i get the output which has Column name

Comment: Are you missing from clause?? Query posted should be like: Select count(*) From tbl_images WHERE SalesOrganization = '5000'

Comment: Maybe try changing to `dbo.TBL_Images` perhaps the database is case sensitive (although I see your columns aren't). Or maybe it's picking up a different table owned by another user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `from` clause in your query

```
Select count(*) from tbl_images WHERE SalesOrganization = '5000'
```